# writing data to html page

Tags: php, javascript, html

I am retrieving data from facebook and trying to print it.
Using console.log(data) I can write in console. but how can I print or write so that I can show it on my page in div?

```
function CallAfterLogin(){
        FB.login(function(response) {
        if (response.status === "connected")
        {
            LodingAnimate(); //Animate login
            FB.api('/me', function(data) {
            console.log(data);
              if(data.email == null)
              {
                    //Facbeook user email is empty, you can check something like this.
                  alert("You must allow us to access your email id!");
                    ResetAnimate();

              }else{
                    AjaxResponse();
              } }); 
         }     });  }
```

I tried with

`$("#mydiv").html(data);` which does not work.

Comment: use `$("#mydiv).append(data.email)`

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
$("#mydiv").text(data);
```

Please see [here](http://api.jquery.com/text/)

Answer (score 1):

Create a div in your `HTML`:

```
<div id="results"></div>
```

In your `JS` function `AjaxResponse(data);` write:

```
$("#results").text( JSON.stringify(data) );
```

Comment: If you're going to implement this functionality in the `AjaxResponse` function, be sure to pass the `data` object to that function as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use either

```
$("#mydiv").text(data);
```

or

```
$("#mydiv").append(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use this plugin: http://www.pionect.nl/files/jquery.dump.js
JsFiddle with demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ZkN5U/1/

Example of use:

```
$('#selector').dump(object)
```

Answer (score 1):

In Internet Explorer up to and including version 9, setting the text content of an HTML element may corrupt the text nodes of its children that are being removed from the document as a result of the operation.

If you are keeping references to these DOM elements and need them to be unchanged, use `.empty().html(string)` instead of `.html(string)` so that the elements are removed from the document before the new string is assigned to the element.

Check out this [empty()](http://api.jquery.com/empty/) and [html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

Try this :

```
$("#mydiv").empty().html(data);
```

instead of:

```
$("#mydiv").html(data);
```

Hope this will help you.